# Array constrain and vlookup formula issue in google sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, vlookup

I am having trouble getting a formula to work in google sheets, the formula is below. It creates an error.

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(ISOWEEKNUM(TODAY()-2),{Personel!H5:H56,Personel!G5:G56},2,FALSE)), 1, 1)
```

Here is a link to the google sheets tracker: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z6rvvD0YGeT1hnuUcP2iNP9spJb9D6Ho/edit#gid=485672745

This formula has worked for calendar year 2023, when I updated to 2024 I noticed the formulas no longer worked. I don't know if this is related to the issue or not.

Answer (score 1):

*the range `{Personel!H5:H56,Personel!G5:G56}` in your vloookup formula is missing **#isoweeknumber 1** → which is in `Personel!H4`; so the error*

*Change it to `{Personel!H4:H55,Personel!G4:G55}`*